# $_FILES перенаправить на другой сервер

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой при отправке $_FILES ,   система такая что я получаю $_FILES от внешнего сервера через POST обрабатываю его ( формирую доп параметры ) и хочу отправляю на сервер для хранения изображений с новыми параметрами

сервер для хранения тоже хочет принимать $_FILES но у меня не получается сформировать

Коллеги подскажите как мне правильно принять и отправить $_FILES 
пытаюсь отправлять на сервер через curl

```
 $curlOptions = [
        CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($this->sendParams),
        CURLOPT_URL            => $this->url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    ];
```

но curl мне не отправляет  $_FILES
как правильно это сделать ?

Answer (score 2):

Для отправки файлов через curl вам необходимо передавать в `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` не строку, а массив. То есть удалите `http_build_query`.

В массиве параметров представьте необходимые для отправки файлы через объекты `CURLFile`

```
$this->sendParams['uploadfile'] = new \CURLFile(
    $tmpFilename // имя из $_FILES['tmp_name']
);
```

Если необходимо, заполните `mime`-тип и имя файла как его увидит удалённый сервер.

Comment: да так и есть параметр http_build_query ломал мою переменную _FILES  , все получилось , спасибо